# Questions about permissions, specifically across machines

Tags: macos, unix, permission

I've got a couple of external HDDs and I've noticed the permissions on them are differ, which has got me wondering how a few things work.

On the hard drive that seems to be normal, it has the following permissions on machine 1 (as seen in the info panel):

```
myuser1 (Me) - Read & Write
staff        - Read & Write
everyone     - Read only
```

Now when connecting it to my second computer, the user I'm logged in as still has write permissions. When viewing the permissions again I see:

```
myuser2 (Me) - Read & Write
staff        - Read & Write
everyone     - Read only
```

1) I the reason that this second computer has R&W permissions because `myuser2` is also a member of `staff`?

2) If so how is the `staff` group on one machine determined to be logically the same as a group named `staff` on another machine? I.e. security wise, how is this secure?

How are users and groups referenced in the file's permissions, in a way that is "secure", yet somehow works across 2 completely separate machines? Is it done by name? uid? gid (for groups)? Either way, as these aren't UUIDs, how can this be classed as secure? One could simply ensure a user is created has the same uid as is required to view a file that they're not supposed to see, and they'll have access!

Comment: You had a bunch of questions in your text, this site works much better if there is only one question per post. I've removed the additional things you've asked, please ask them in new questions if required.

Comment: Sorry I'm not too happy about that. All the questions are all extremely related. Should anyone be struggling with understanding the same things, it would all be helpful and related information.

Comment: @patrix And while there were many "questions", they were all extremely related to understanding a single concept. I've enjoyed many very long and comprehensive answers on this site. Sometimes comprehensive answers require comprehensive questions. Perhaps it would help to simply remove my helpful numbered points on each of the question areas, and instead allow someone to read my confusions and then answer with a single response. Plus it took me time to condense my problems into those questions. Please can you re-think your edit?

Comment: @Sencha you can restore your original question by yourself. After reading the original question I advise to condense all seven questions to one or two

Comment: As mentioned by klanomath you can always rollback any edits made to your question. Based on past experience, long questions tend to result in bad or incomplete answers so I'm not sure whether it will really help in your case. It might be better to get answers on a trimmed down version of what you don't fully "get" regarding permissions (that's what I tried to get at with my edit) and then ask follow-up questions once you got the initial roadblocks out of the way. A good answer on the edited question should already cover several of the additional issues anyway.

Comment: Okay, I'll try and condense/crystallise my questions into a smaller post. Thank you!

Comment: Or wait til tomorrow. I have an idea for a comprehensive answer, but need some time to write it :-)

Comment: Even better, somebody else already did. Also, can you check (in Disk Utility) whether ownership checks are enabled for the external drive at all?

Comment: @patrix "Owners enabled" is set to `No` in disk utility info. Should it be `Yes`? Looking into it, strangely the checkbox [discussed here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22141) isn't visible to me. So not sure what is happening there.

Comment: If it is set to No, the whole "who owns what and can access which files" discussion is kind of pointless. OTOH, setting it to "No" solves most of the problems the typical user has when sharing USB sticks or external hard drives. If you want your data to be secure on a removable media, use encryption.

Answer (score 5):

First some important commands to know:

`ls -laO` shows a lot:

```
drwxrwxr-x+ 19 myuser1  staff   714  2 Feb 10:31 My Passport
```

`ls -elaO` includes ACLs:

```
drwxrwxr-x+ 19 myuser1  staff   714  2 Feb 10:31 My Passport
  0: user:_spotlight inherited allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
```

The following command shows all members of a group (the example group here is staff):

```
members () { dscl . -list /Users | while read user; do printf "$user "; dsmemberutil checkmembership -U "$user" -G "$*"; done | grep "is a member" | cut -d " " -f 1; }; members staff
```

The following command shows the UID, the GID and the group memberships of user_name

```
id user_name
```

Please check your various users/groups with the last two commands to get an overview.

---

Standard permissions in the file system are applied by using UID and GID instead of names. So

```
drwxrwxr-x+ 19 myuser1  staff   714  2 Feb 10:31 My Passport
```

should be read as (assuming myuser1's UID=501):

```
drwxrwxr-x+ 19 UID=501  GID=20   714  2 Feb 10:31 My Passport
 |  |  |
 |  |  |Others (Members of GID=12 (Everyone)?) can read and execute
 |  |Members of GID=20 can read, write and execute
 |UID=501 can read, write and execute (owner)
```

Attaching *My Passport* to another Mac (Mac2) - the UID/GID won't be changed - will reveal the following:

- In case myuser2's UID=501 and GID=20 (GID=20 (staff) is a standard group on every Mac and every (standard or admin) user created with the System Preferences is member of it)

  ```
  drwxrwxr-x+ 19 UID=501  GID=20   714  2 Feb 10:31 My Passport
  ```

  which retranslates to:

  ```
  drwxrwxr-x+ 19 myuser2  staff  714  2 Feb 10:31 My Passport
  ```

  and myuser2 on Mac2 has the same rights as myuser1 on Mac1
- In case myuser2's UID=502 and myuser3's UID=501 and both are member of *staff*:

  ```
  drwxrwxr-x+ 19 myuser3  staff  714  2 Feb 10:31 My Passport
  ```

  myuser2 as member of *staff* isn't owner anymore but can still rwx.
- In case myuser2's UID=502 and is member of *staff* and **myuser3 with UID=501 has been deleted**:

  ```
  drwxrwxr-x+ 19 (unknown user)  staff  714  2 Feb 10:31 My Passport
  ```

  myuser2 as member of *staff* isn't owner anymore but can still rwx.
- In case myuser2's UID=503 and is **not** member of *staff* and UID=501 is deleted

  ```
  drwxrwxr-x+ 19 (unknown user)  staff  714  2 Feb 10:31 My Passport
  ```

  myuser2 as *others* (member of *everyone*?) can rx.

---

So to answer your questions: the reason why myuser2 on Mac2 has the same rights as myuser1 on Mac1 are the same UID and GID/group memberships of both on their respective host. *Staff* is a default group on every Mac.

In your current environment (single machines/admin rights for the main user(s)) using external drives is not "secure/save" - only using permissions to determine access. And it was never meant to be.

In an organizational unit (the common user of a workstation is **no** admin) with a centralized user management (OD etc.) you may use applied mount points and special groups do deal with external drives:

Special owner and a new group for the drive/mountpoint:

```
drwxrwx--- 19 UID=501  GID=512   714  2 Feb 10:31 My Passport
```

or

```
drwxrwx--- 19 UID=501  GID=512   714  2 Feb 10:31 My Passport/share_folder
```

and all non-admin users which require access to the external drive(s) are member of GID=512 ("External Drive Users")

---

Still, when the external drive is lost, anyone may have access to it. To make it secure you have to encrypt the content of the external disks.

Comment: In the standard unix permission model there is only one `owner`and one `group` classification. `Everyone` is synonymous with Others, meaning that the user neither is the owner nor belongs the the file's group classification.

Comment: @fd0 In this unix model, can you clarify if this `group` classification is always the same group as the `owner`'s group, or can they be different?

Comment: @klanomath Thanks so much for this detailed answer. I'm working my way through it now!

Answer (score 1):

You asking for a lot of information re the Unix security model which I suspect is too much for one answer here.

The piece of informatiom you are after are User ids (UID) and group ids (GID) This a numeric values corresponding to user and group names.

You can see what they are by `id <username>` e.g. on my computer

```
~/D/c/TV $ id mark
uid=502(mark) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),399(com.apple.access_ssh),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing)
```

This shows that my user id is 502 my main group is staff*20( and lists the other groups I am in.

Across machines the user and group are equal is they have the same number which is the answer to 2. You are sort of correct it is not that secure but in a managed network the logins will be centrally controlled so only authorised users can connect like this.

As for 3) the volume is mounted to a directory on the client computer and the permissions shown are for that link. So like a symbolic link the info on the name you use to access the other thing can differ from the permission on the source.

For 4) each file/directory is owned by a user, and has permissions for a group and also for all users

Comment: Thanks for the info. When you say "and has permissions for a group", can you please clarify if that "group" you talk about is always the group of the owner user, or can you set a different group?

Comment: Also @Mark, regarding your answer to (3), how can I properly check the permissions of the source volume, if accessing it via the `/Volumes/My Passport` mount point isn't correct?